# Any alternative ways to lua_setfield? (Lua C/C++)

Tags: c++, lua

I'm using lua C functions, but I can't use lua_setfield. I need something that can do basically what lua_setfield does. I can use any other lua function except for lua_setfield. Any help?

Comment: Why can't you use `lua_setfield`?

Answer (score 2):

If `i` is positive (i.e., absolute), then `lua_setfield(L,i,k)` is equivalent to

```
lua_pushstring(L,k);
lua_insert(L,-2);
lua_settable(L,i);
```

If `i` is negative (i.e., relative), then `lua_setfield(L,i,k)` is equivalent to

```
lua_pushstring(L,k);
lua_insert(L,-2);
lua_settable(L,i-1);
```

The code below combines these two:

```
lua_pushstring(L,k);
lua_insert(L,-2);
lua_settable(L,i-(i<0));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the amazing help!